# fabric8 v6.1.1 Failure at creating Custom Resource with POST call Resulting in Not Found

Tags: java, cucumber, fabric8, fabric8-kubernetes-client

New to fabric8 K8S client library. Recently was trying to create a custom resource object using fabric8 (v6.1.1) and got Not Found Message at the POST Call internally. Can list on the CRD client on which this POST is performed.

```
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://cluster-xyz.domain.com/apis/<resource spec.group>/v1/<crdname>. Message: Not Found.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:713)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:693)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:644)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.lambda$handleResponse$0(OperationSupport.java:581)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:616)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:591)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.OperationSupport.lambda$retryWithExponentialBackoff$2(OperationSupport.java:622)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientImpl$4.onResponse(OkHttpClientImpl.java:268)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Created a CRD client in code and able to list on it :

```
MixedOperation<CRD_POJO, KubernetesResourceList<CRD_POJO>, Resource<CRD_POJO>> CRDClient = apiClient.resources(CRD_POJO.class);
        System.out.println("CRDclient List:::::" + CRDClient.list());
```

Till this point it works fine and I am able to list the objects as well but after that created a custom object of type CRD and tried doing a create on the CRD client and it failed with the above error.

```
CRD_POJO CR = new CRD_POJO();
// Some set operations to make the CR object ready
...
CRD_POJO created = CRDClient.inNamespace("test").createOrReplace(CR);//Here it fails
```

Anyone faced this or know any solution? Any lead will help to solve this issue

Comment: Could you please show how you've configured `@Group`, `@Plural` and `@Version` annotations in CRD_POJO?

Comment: @RohanKumar Like below:
```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value ={"status"})
@Version("v1")
@Group("<resource spec.group>")
public class CRD_POJO extends CustomResource<CRD_POJOSpec, CRD_POJOStatus> {
.....
}
```

Comment: Is it a namespaced scope crd? If yes, you need to add `implements Namespaced`

Comment: @RohanKumar Yes. I figured out that and it started working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RohanKumar pointed, implementing the "Namespaced" interface in this case solved the issue.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value ={"status"}) @Version("v1") @Group("<resource spec.group>") public class CRD_POJO extends CustomResource<CRD_POJOSpec, CRD_POJOStatus> implements Namespaced { ..... }
```